# Vertical blinds, drywall only no stud

Tags: drywall-anchor, blinds

Trying to install vertical blinds for 2 slider doors and I cannot locate any stud/plywood backing in the areas I need to drill the holes for the mounting brackets.

- Have any of you used pop toggle anchors in this situation and has it lasted?
- I have 4 brackets only included in the package, would that be sufficient to hold the vinyl blinds (around 96 inches wide, 80 inches tall

What other options do I realistically have? Not trying to open up the walls if it can be avoided.

Comment: There are quite a few similar questions to be found. Here's one. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/75487/2-3kg-blinds-into-drywall-plasterboard?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2-3kg blinds into drywall/plasterboard](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/75487/2-3kg-blinds-into-drywall-plasterboard)

Comment: Thanks. I am just not sure if they will hold in that area above the slide, it seems very flimsy to me.
I was thinking of pop toggle bolts as the holes are smaller if there are any issues., the toggle bolts make a pretty big hole and the hole I need to make leaves only 1.5inches to the end of the recessed wall above the slider, sufficient to simply rotate the toggle bolts so they spread parallel to the wall?

Comment: A picture of the installation area and the blinds will help. Normally there is plenty of frame around a sliding glass door, so pictures will help us give you a better answer.

Comment: I'll try to get a better picture later. Basically the area in green has a depth of 3.5 inches. The bracket installation calls for drilling the hole 2 inches in, so that I am left with 1.5 inches to the front.

https://imgur.com/BGxrIAh

Headrail was this one from home depot :
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-78-in-W-Head-Rail-for-3-1-2-in-Vertical-Blind-in-White-10793478808564/300147149

Bl;inds just the standard vinyl blinds they have cut in length:
And 4 packs of these

Comment: Louvers https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-3-5-in-W-x-84-in-L-Crown-White-3-5-in-Vertical-Blind-Louver-Set-9-pack-10793478808588/300146854